# On uniformly continuous, bounded, hermitian functions whose product is continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be uniformly continuous, such that $f(0)=g(0)=1$, $|f(x)|\le 1, |g(x)|\le 1,\forall x\in \mathbb R$, $f(-t)=\overline {f(t)}, g(-t)=\overline {g(t)}, \forall t \in \mathbb R$ and $f.g$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

Then is it true that $f,g$ are differentiable at $0$ ? If this is not true in general, what if we also assume that $f,g$ are real-valued ?

Answer (score 0):

Define $r(x)=\frac1{|x|+1}$ and take $f(x)=r(x)+i\sigma(x)\sqrt{1-(r(x))^2}$ and $g(x)=\overline{f(x)}$. Here $\sigma(x)$ is the sign of $x$. Notice that $r$ is not differentiable at $0$, so neither are $f$ and $g$. However $|f(x)|=1$, so $fg=1$, so $fg$ is continuously differentiable. All the other properties are easier to check.

Now, to prove that the conjecture does hold for $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$ with $1-f(x)>\varepsilon|x|$. Since $|g(x)|\leq1$, we then also find $1-(fg)(x)>\varepsilon|x|$ (for $x$ small enough such that $f(x)>0$). Hence $fg$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: If $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, then $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that $\forall \delta >0$, $\exists x_\delta \in (-\delta, \delta)$ with $|\dfrac {1-f(x_\delta)}{x_\delta}-f'(0)|>\epsilon$ ... from here how do you get $1-f(x_\delta)>\delta \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Sorry, minor mistake, the $\delta\epsilon$ should have been $\epsilon x$. For further explanation, I use that $f(0)=1$ and I use in particular that $f'(0)\neq0$. I actually only show that the derivative of $fg$ at $0$ can not be $0$, however this is the only thing it can be, as $fg$ attains a global maximum at $0$.

Comment: do you mean to say that you're using $f'(0)=0$ ? I don't see how $f'(0)\ne 0$ gets you the required inequality ...

Comment: We assume $f$ is not differentiable. In particular $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\neq0$. By definition there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x)-1}{x}\right|>\varepsilon$, so $|1-f(x)|>\varepsilon|x|$.